# Testing redux's ConnectedComponent

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have been trying to test redux's ConnectedComponent. But I can't get along with it. When I pass the store to a ConnectedComponent as a store prop I get this error:

> Invariant Violation: Passing redux store in props has been removed and does not do anything. To use a custom Redux store for specific components,
>    create a custom React context with React.createContext(), and pass the context object to React-Redux's Provider and specific components like:  . You may also pass a {context : MyContext} option to connect

My test:

```
const store = storeFactory({ success: true });
test('renders component without error', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Input store={store} />);

  expect(wrapper.props()).toBe({});
});
```

I use a helper function that creates a store:

```
export const storeFactory = initialState => {
  return createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
};
```

I use this versions of packages:

```
"react-redux": "^6.0.0",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"enzyme": "^3.8.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
"enzyme-redux": "^0.2.1",
"jest": "^23.6.0",
"jest-enzyme": "^7.0.1"
```

I don't know how to test ConnectedComponent.
Please, if you have any solutions or suggestions for this situation share it  with me))

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in React-Redux v6, [we removed the ability to pass `store` as a prop to connected components](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/#v6-0), because of internal architecture changes.

I'll be honest and say that shallow rendering a connected component seems pointless to me, because all you're really testing is that `connect` calls your `mapState` and `mapDispatch` and passes the combined results to your own component.  We already have tests for React-Redux that verify that behavior :)

However, there do seem to be people that want to do this.  We've got [an open issue to discuss how we can help handle the "shallow+connected" use case](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1161).  No ETA on specific changes to the API, but please keep an eye on that issue.

Comment: I think I should just test props instead of the store as described here https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md#connected-components